# Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap`

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

If I got will get an unsure rows JSON data. How should I set of my class?

This is my current class

```
public class ChatMessage {

private Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> any(){
    return this.message;
}

public Map<String, String> getMessage() {
    return this.message;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setMessage(String key, String value) {
    message.put(key, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Message [message=" + message + "]";
}
}
```

this is my json send from js

```
{"type":"message","user":"james","to":"","message":"Hi every"}
```

I got error now

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not 
read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although 
at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method 
to deserialize from String value ('Welcome james join the room')
at [Source: (byte[])" . 
{"type":"message","user":"james","to":"","message":"Welcome james join the 
room"}"; line: 1, column: 52] (through reference chain: 
chat.model.ChatMessage["message"]); nested exception is         
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct         
instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): 
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String 
value ('Welcome james join the room')
at [Source: (byte[])" . 
{"type":"message","user":"james","to":"","message":"Welcome james join the 
room"}"; line: 1, column: 52] (through reference chain: 
chat.model.ChatMessage["message"])
```

because my json would be like

```
{"type":"message",
 "user":"james",
 "to":"",
 "message":"Welcome james join the room",
 "xxx":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

or

```
{"type":"message",
 "user":"james",
 "to":"",
 "message":"Welcome james join the room",
 "yyy":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

how should I set my class?
Thx

Comment: how is this working? did you tried to check after converting to object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename either the `message` field in the json or `message` field in the POJO.
As per your POJO structure, jackson is trying to deserialize `"message":"Hi every"` to the message field in your POJO and is not able to create a Map out of it (Since it's just a String).

Your code will work with following json:

```
{"type":"message","user":"james","to":"","json-message":"Hi every"}
```

OR

following POJO:

```
public class ChatMessage {

private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> any(){
    return this.map;
}

public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return this.map;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setMap(String key, String value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Map [map=" + map + "]";
}
}
```

Comment: if we try to change the objectname from message to json-message, how jackson-object mapper would identify and convert to object?